# dynamic radio button text alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

When i add a radio button in visual c# the text name of the radio button is aligned perfectly to the right . if i create a radio button dynamically and give it several properties etc.. when i debug and view it, the text or name of the radio button is shifted slighted up and to the right of the radio button?  i am looked over several properties including padding etc.. but i am not able to figure out how to correct this dynamically. what is going on and how can i fix this?

here is example of the properties i am using right now

```
radio_ip_addresses[i] = new RadioButton();
radio_ip_addresses[i].Name = "radio_" + i;
radio_ip_addresses[i].Text = ip_addresses.Dequeue();
radio_ip_addresses[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
radio_ip_addresses[i].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
radio_ip_addresses[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
radio_ip_addresses[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
radio_ip_addresses[i].Visible = true;
radio_ip_addresses[i].Parent = this;
```

[image: image of winform]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is this winforms? Which version?

Comment: yes .net 4, thanks. i edited with an image, you can see i just plugged in the pre-built radio button and the text is aligned, but on the radios i create in my array and give them the properties you see above, you can see the text is little off. i am just getting the ip addresses on the local host and saving them in a  Queue<string> , then i assign each ip address to the .Text value of each radio, i have no idea why it is doing this? also the IP 169.254.105. is missing the 4th octet? i just noticed that also :(

Comment: Have you compared your properties with those assigned in the designer.cs?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Rotem, i took your suggestion to check the designer.cs i should have thought of that. it was autosize that was the key :), see below from what i found in the designer.cs.

```
       this.radioButton1.AutoSize = true;
        this.radioButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(192, 50);
        this.radioButton1.Name = "radioButton1";
        this.radioButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 17);
        this.radioButton1.TabIndex = 71;
        this.radioButton1.TabStop = true;
        this.radioButton1.Text = "radioButton1";
        this.radioButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```